# i made a loop that did calculations now i want to sum my results in assembly

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16

We are task to take 5 input from the user

the input number should be subtracted from 9 and then we should total all the total differences

eg input 5,2,4,7,1        9-5= 4 , 9-2=7, 9-4=5, 9-7= 2, 9-1= 8 
then we are required to add the results so 4+7+5+2+8= 26

and display the result of

I have made to calculation ans place them in a loop but the sum only show the value of the last calculation and not the sum

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data

 num1 db
 num2 db 9
 result db ?
 sum db

 msg1 db 10, 13,"Enter a number: $", 10, 13
 msg2 db 10, 13,"Difference is: $",10, 13
 msg3 db 10, 13,"Sum is: $",10, 13

 .code
     main proc

     mov ax, @data
        mov ds, ax

        mov cx,5

        process:

        mov dx, offset msg1
        mov ah,9 ; used to print the string/msg with
        int 21h ;this



        mov ah, 1 ;READ a Character from Console,
                  ;Echo it on screen and save the
                  ;value entered in AL register
        int 21h

        sub al, 30h ;keep the value enter in bcd form
        mov num1, al ;move num1 to al
        ;al is used for input


        ;sub al, 30h
        mov al, num2 ;move num2 to al

        sub al, num1 ;

        mov result, al ;move whats in al to result


        mov bl,al
        add sum,bl
        ;add al,sum

        mov ah,0 ;clears whats in ah
        aaa ;used to convert the result to bcd
        ;and first digit is stored in ah
        ;second digit stored in al


        add ah, 30h ;convert whats in ah to ascii by adding 30h
        add al, 30h ;convert whats in al to ascii by adding 30h
        mov bx, ax ;saving whats in ah and al in bx register



        mov dx, offset msg2
        mov ah,9 ; used to print the string/msg  
        int 21h



        ;the following is used to print whats in the bh register
        ;dl is used for output
        ;2 or 2h means to write/print whats in dl
        ;so the value to be printed is moved to dl
        mov ah,2
        mov dl, bh
        int 21h


        ;the following is used to print whats in bl
        mov ah,2
        mov dl, bl
        int 21h

        loop process

        mov dx, offset msg3
        mov ah,9 ; used to print the string/msg  
        int 21h

        mov ah,2
        mov dl, bh
        int 21h


        ;the following is used to print whats in bl
        mov ah,2
        mov dl, bl
        int 21h

     mov ah, 4ch ;4ch means to return to OS i.e. the end
     ;of program
     int 21h
    main endp ;ends the code
end main ;ends main
```

I expected 26 for my sum.  Instead I am getting 8

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> sum db
> ```

This is missing an operand. Write `sum db 0`

> but the sum only show the value of the last calculation and not the sum

Between displaying the 3rd message and the corresponding value, you forget to re-calculate the required contents of `BX`. You simply re-used what was in there already!

```
    mov dx, offset msg3
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h

    mov al, sum         ADD THIS
    mov ah, 0           ADD THIS
    aaa                 ADD THIS
    add ax, 3030h       ADD THIS
    mov bx, ax          ADD THIS

    mov ah, 02h
    mov dl, bh
    int 21h

    mov ah, 02h
    mov dl, bl
    int 21h

    mov ax, 4C00h
    int 21h
```